# loop ends when function called

Tags: javascript, function, loops

I'm writing what I think is some pretty routine javascript.  However I'm having an issue I can't seem to resolve.  I'm looping through an array and when it reaches the point of a function being called, the loop breaks.  If I take the function out the loops runs to completion.  I can't seem to figure it out.

```
for (i=0;i<response.items.length;i++) {
    console.log("cover: ", decodeURIComponent(response.items[i].coverPhotoPath));                                              
    previewAlbum(decodeURIComponent(response.items[i].coverPhotoPath));
}
```

The code for the function being called is...

```
function previewAlbum(file) {
    console.log("preview", file);
    var galleryId = "photo";
    var gallery = document.getElementById(galleryId);
    var img = document.createElement("img");

    img.style.cssText = 'width:200px;height:200px;';
    img.src = file;
    gallery.appendChild(img);

    // Using FileReader to display the image content
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function(aImg) { return function(e) { aImg.src = e.target.result; }; })(img);
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

}
```

Each piece of code works on it's own.  But when put together the loop breaks.  Any ideas?

Comment: First of all, maybe you should add a `try...catch` to see, if there is an error in console. Second change `for (i=0;` to `for (var i=0;`

Comment: There's probably an unhandled error that is stopping execution. Does "preview" run `response.items.length` times? Try step through the code using a debugger.

Comment: The try catch did it.  found out the FileReader was causing it the issue.  That piece of code isn't even needed.  Thank you both for the help.